# What is the current - voltage relation in a wire?

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, wire, circuit-theory

This is a question from a TV game show. Fill the blank with appropriate words.

> Current flowing through a wire is ... to the voltage drop across the
>   wire.

The answer in the dots is "proportional".

I am wondering if this is really an accurate statement. Should it be "current flowing through **a resistor**..." instead?

Comment: A wire IS a resistor.

Comment: Wires have resistance but a very low resistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wire has inductance (no matter how small) because it produces a magnetic field and if the voltage is AC then the current will not be time-stamped proportional to voltage but somewhat lagging in time (depending on the frequency applied).

> I am wondering if this is really an accurate statement. Should it be
>   "current flowing through a resistor..." instead?

I'd prefer your version because it kind-of naturally excludes inductance being an effect.

Also, because there is no mention of wire length, transmission line effects can screw this simple TV game show answer completely.

Answer (score 3):

Every wire has a resistor which increase with the length. Since it's very small, we normally ignore it. Thanks to Ohm law, we can calculate the dropping voltage due to a resistor : \$U = RI\$, \$I = U * \frac{1}{R}\$. As you can see, the current is proportional to the volage drop by a factor of \$\frac{1}{R}\$

Answer (score 0):

As a wire has some resistance (ignoring superconducting conditions), I say that this is a fine answer.  One volt is the amount of force required to move one ampere of current through one ohm of resistance.  This would make the current proportional to voltage for a fixed resistance.

Comment: Volts don't measure force but potential difference. I guess you're trying to simplify this for a beginner reader, but this kind of sloppiness is likely to just make them more confused.

Comment: it was the simplest path.  feel free to make edits